# Xpath 1.0: Cannot get the value of a specific element. Duplicate values returned

Tags: xpath

I have the following piece of XML:

```
<Resource>
    <ResourceSummaryBag>
        <Entry>
            <ObjectName>NR_LDI</ObjectName>
            <usage_prm>
                <Entry>
                    <UsedEntries>98416</UsedEntries>
                </Entry>         
            </usage_prm>
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
            <ObjectName>R_LDI</ObjectName>
            <usage_prm>
                <Entry>
                    <UsedEntries>13265</UsedEntries>
                </Entry>
            </usage_prm>
        </Entry>
    </ResourceSummaryBag>
</Resource>
```

I want to extract *usage_prm/UsedEntries* values by *ObjectName* element.
If I use contains, I get duplicate values for '**R_LDI**' object but I want the values for the specific **R_LDI** and **NR_LDI** objects.

```
Resource/ResourceSummaryBag/Entry[./ObjectName[contains(.,'R_LDI')]]/usage_prm/Entry/UsedEntries
```

Result: 98416 13265

Any solution? 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `=` + `normalize-space()` instead of `contains()`:

```
./ObjectName[normalize-space()='R_LDI']
```

`normalize-space()` *strips leading and trailing white-space from a string, replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space, and returns the resulting string* <sup>[[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space)]</sup>